# Yii framework not showing image link on menu array

Tags: yii

very green on Yii... would appreciate any help.

the code below uses an image (home icon) as a link to obviously my Home page. The link works (its the first item on the menu) and the home page displays, but the image is not showing... any idea?

```
$top_menu[]=array('tag'=>"signup",CHtml::image(Yii::app()->request->baseUrl.'assets/images/home-blue.jpg',array("width"=>"100px" ,"height"=>"100px")),'url'=> websiteUrl());
```

Answer (score 0):

According to documentation

> Returns the relative URL for the application. This is similar to scriptUrl except that it does not have the script file name, and the ending slashes are stripped off.

So, add slash

```
Yii::app()->request->baseUrl . '/assets/images/home-blue.jpg'
```

Comment: thank you very much... such a stupid miss on my part.